# Heroku slug size for Play project exceeding 300mb when deployed from gitlab ci

Tags: heroku, travis-ci, gitlab-ci

I have a `Play` application which I deploy using `gitlab`'s CI.
I've defined the deploy task in `.gitlab-ci.yml` as:

```
deploy-project:
    stage: deploy
    script:
        - echo "Executing deploy-project job"
        - dpl --provider=heroku --app=my-heroku-app-name --api-key=$HEROKU_STAGING_API_KEY
```

as explained here: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ci/blob/master/doc/examples/test-and-deploy-python-application-to-heroku.md

When I push to my `origin`, this deployment runs and fails, with the error that the slug size is too large (~357mb).
But when I deploy the app from my local machine by doing a `git push heroku master`, the slug size is only ~223mb.
Also, when I deploy from `github`, the slug size is ~223mb.

Why is the slug size increasing when I use Travis' `dpl` to deploy?

Travis dpl: https://github.com/travis-ci/dpl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem disappeared when I changed the `dpl` strategy from the default `anvil` to `git`:

```
dpl --provider=heroku --app=my-heroku-app-name --api-key=$HEROKU_STAGING_API_KEY --strategy=git
```

Not sure what the difference between the two strategies is. Any info on that would be appreciated.